# OS X AVPlayer AirPlay Video to Apple TV

Tags: macos, video-streaming, avfoundation, avplayer

In the AVFoundation framework for iOS, AVPlayer has an external airplay property. I'm looking to achieve the same with AVPlayer for OS X which does not have this property available. How can my AVPlayer stream the video from my MacBook Pro to my Apple TV through airplay?

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing for a while, unfortunately the API isn't exposed yet, not even in Yosemite... or at least all my efforts finding it failed :(

Answer (score 0):

It's actually handled by `CoreAudio` (OS X 10.8+). You should be able to interact with AppleTV, etc. through `AudioDeviceID`.

There's a [really good explanation here](http://joris.kluivers.nl/blog/2012/07/25/per-application-airplay-in-mountain-lion/), and an example application on bitbucket [here](http://bitbucket.org/kluivers/airplaystreaming).